# hbase zookeeper: Which one come first on AWS environement?

Tags: python, hadoop, amazon-web-services, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I set up a Hadoop environment on my AWS free tier. it is 1 master-3 slaves running hadoop 2.7.1 - Ubuntu 14.04 (not EMR).

**Now** I would like to go to the next step and it looked like HBase was a good starting point. after reading further I noticed Zookeeper is coming into the picture...

**Question**: After setting up hadoop, should I install and configure HBase multi node or Zookeeper and then HBase *(sqoop, flume, pig ... should follow the completion of this step)?*

**Bonus**: My intent is to connect R, Tableau like visualization software and run few python programs to play with AWS so **recommendation-suggestion are welcome**

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Apache HBase Documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/zookeeper.html), A distributed Apache HBase (TM) installation depends on a running ZooKeeper cluster. All participating nodes and clients need to be able to access the running ZooKeeper ensemble. Apache HBase by default manages a ZooKeeper "cluster" for you. So, It is not needed to install ZooKeeper at first.

I recommend you to use Python PyData Modules for visualization(SciPy and etc) when you want to write python programs instead of R or Tableau integration for Python. They are very powerful and easy to use.

Comment: Hi Mobin! thank you for your views on this. I browse some additional material and some guys recommend to install ZK first rather than using the HBase default relation. The argument here is to separate Zookeper from HBase if I want to stop using HBase in the future. What are your views on this ? Agree-Disagree?

Comment: Disagree. I have quoted it from the original reference. What is their reference? They have recommended to install but it is not needed/required. Maybe you have to look for pros and cons of each.